# Que mime-type para csv se debe usar en PHP

Tags: mongodb, csv, php7

estoy haciendo una aplicación en PHP que exporta datos de un archivo CSV a una base de datos en MongoDB. En el método que utilizo hago una validación de que el archivo que se va a cargar sea un CSV, esto lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
$archivocargado = $ficherocarga . basename($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);
            $mime_types = array('text/plain', 
                'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                'application/vnd.msexcel',
                'text/csv',
                'application/csv', 
                'text/comma-separated-values',          
                'application/octet-stream', 
                'text/tab-separated-values',
                'text/tsv',
                'application/x-csv');

                if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $mime_types)){
                    //cargar datos del archivo
                }else{
                    echo "Archivo no válido, cargue un archivo CSV";
                }
```

Utilizo un array de mime-types que he encontrado para que estos verifiquen el tipo de archivo que se carga, sin embargo cuando lo pruebo me dice que el archivo no es el correcto. A que se debe esto y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces un `var_dump($_FILES);` para ver qué información tiene el archivo? ¿Cómo puedes asegurar que hay realmente un archivo?

Comment: @A. Cenado hice lo que me dijiste y obtuve el siguiente array: array(1) { ["archivo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(29) "CR8_Mux_LosHum_Temp_15min.csv" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } }. Aparte de eso yo  utilizo la función mime_content_type() y le paso como parámetro  la variable $archivocargado, que contiene el archivo, esta me devuelve "text/plain", dicha función la coloco en el echo que dice que el archivo no es valido

Comment: Ahí dice que el `type` está vacío. ¿No será un archivo dañado el que estás manejando? ¿Cómo se genera ese archivo? ¿Qué pasa si pruebas con un `.csv` válido, entendido por válido, que lo puedas abrir correctamente desde un editor de textos?

Comment: Creo que ya vi el problema. El `var_dump` muestra **un código de error `1`**. [Según el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php), ese código de error indica que **el fichero supera el tamaño máximo permitido**. O el archivo es demasiado grande, o tu valor de `upload_max_filesize` es demasiado pequeño. Prueba con un archivo más pequeño. Eso significa además que deberías establecer en tu código un control de errores para ser informado sobre situaciones como esta.

Comment: @A. Cedano Entiendo, de hecho este mismo método lo ejecuto con un otro csv con las mismas características y funciona, y de hecho el archivo que funciona tiene menos datos que el csv que trato de cargar, entonces el problema sería el tamaño del archivo, ¿que puedo hacer para que me acepte el archivo con este o mayor tamaño?

Comment: Eso sería tema para una nueva pregunta. Si quieres aporto una respuesta como solución para este caso y la nueva duda la planteas en una nueva pregunta, habiendo buscado previamente si el asunto no ha sido ya preguntado. Ten en cuenta que SO funciona por preguntas y está pensado para ayudar a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema. Si cambiamos una pregunta de tema ya nos salimos del formato del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El array de tipos MIME que muestras contiene hasta ahora los posibles tipos que podría tener un archivo CSV.

Echando mano de un gran amigo que tienes en PHP y que nunca debes olvidar: **`var_dump`**, si muestras lo que hay en `$_FILES` con:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Obtienes esto:

```
array(1) { 
            ["archivo"]=> 
                            array(5) { 
                                        ["name"]=> string(29) "CR8_Mux_LosHum_Temp_15min.csv" 
                                        ["type"]=> string(0) "" 
                                        ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" 
                                        ["error"]=> int(1) 
                                        ["size"]=> int(0) 
                                      } 
        }
```

El estado del objeto muestra dos cosas:

1. Que no hay nada en la clave `type`
2. Que hay un código de `error 1`

Les códigos de mensaje de error que ocurren en `$_FILES` [son explicados en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php). De error `1` dice lo siguiente:

> ```
> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
> ```
>
> Valor: 1; El fichero subido excede la directiva
>   [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) de `php.ini`.

El problema entonces es que tu archivo es más grande del tamaño permitido por la directiva `upload_max_filesize` especificada en el archivo `php.ini`.

#### Soluciones

- Corregir esa anomalía, sea disminuyendo el tamaño del archivo, optimizándolo o dividiéndolo en partes. Si el archivo no es excesivamente grande, puede que alguien haya trasteado con los valores de `php.ini` y haya puesto un tamaño demasiado pequeño como límite (esto es menos probable).
- En cuanto al archivo, controlar primeramente en el cliente que no se puedan subir archivos que excedan cierta capacidad y establecer quizá también un control en el servidor en ese sentido. En todo caso ese es ya otro tema que debería ser tratado aparte.